# Amplitude fit - driven harmonic oscillator with damping

Tags: fitting

The **equation of motion** for a driven damped harmonic motion is:

$m\ddot{x}+k\dot{x}+Dx=F_0 \cos{\omega x}$

whereby:

$F_0$ : amplitude of the periodic force

$D$: "spring constant"

$k$: the damping constant

$m$: mass

$\omega=2\pi f$: angular frequency

The **amplitude variation vs. frequency** is given by:

$A(\omega)=\frac{F_0}{\sqrt{m^2(w_o^2-w^2)^2+k^2\omega^2}}$

whereby:

$\omega_0$: resonace frequency

> I have measured the amplitude variation as function of the angular
>   frequency and want to determine by fitting $F_0$, $k$, $\omega_0$.

The mass $m$ is known.

Here is my code:

```
data = Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/X7tZeQni"];

m = 6.13652*10^-13;

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, F0/Sqrt[m^2*(w0^2 - w^2)^2 + k^2*w^2], {w0, k, F0}, w];

Show[ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"omega", "amplitude"}], 
 Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 40}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Unfortunately I am not able to fit the measurements, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@MichaelSeifert has provided the general answer:  good starting values are worth their weight in gold.  But how to get good starting values?  (I'd argue that having small values - very close to zero - is not the problem in this case.)

In many cases one can pick the same number of points as there are parameters then use `Solve` or `NSolve` to get starting values.  Here I pick the first and last point and a point near the peak:

```
n = Length[data];
nPeak = Floor[n/4];
Solve[{
  F0/Sqrt[m^2*(w0^2 - data[[1, 1]]^2)^2 + k^2*data[[1, 1]]^2] == data[[1, 2]], 
  F0/Sqrt[m^2*(w0^2 - data[[nPeak, 1]]^2)^2 + k^2*data[[nPeak, 1]]^2] == data[[nPeak, 2]], 
  F0/Sqrt[m^2*(w0^2 - data[[n, 1]]^2)^2 + k^2*data[[n, 1]]^2] == data[[n, 2]]},
  {F0, w0, k}, Reals]
```

This results in a warning and 4 possibilities for starting values:

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact
>   coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact
>   system and numericizing the result. >>

```
{{F0 -> 1.74027*10^-17, w0 -> -7.80111, k -> -7.81643*10^-13},
 {F0 -> 1.74027*10^-17, w0 -> -7.80111, k -> 7.81643*10^-13},
 {F0 -> 1.74027*10^-17, w0 -> 7.80111, k -> -7.81643*10^-13},
 {F0 -> 1.74027*10^-17, w0 -> 7.80111, k -> 7.81643*10^-13}}
```

Using the last element of the above solution for the starting values:

```
data = Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/X7tZeQni"];

m = 6.13652*10^-13;

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  F0/Sqrt[m^2*(w0^2 - w^2)^2 + k^2*w^2], {{F0, 
    1.7402685071446624*^-17}, {w0, 7.801112679932642}, {k, 
    7.81642643816778*^-13}}, w]
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {F0 -> 2.35929*10^-17, w0 -> 8.39465, k -> 2.55192*10^-12} *)

Show[ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"omega", "amplitude"}], 
 Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 40}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

***A small update***

When the parameter estimates differ by many orders of magnitude as in this case, it is usually a good idea to run the estimation again but with the parameters scaled so that they are all in the same ballpark.  This can give a better estimate of the parameter covariance and correlation matrices which can be used to construct confidence bands for the regression (not to mention confidence intervals for the parameters).  Without scaling we get the following for the correlation matrix:

```
nlm["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1. & -0.863768 & 0.863768 \\
 -0.863768 & 1. & -1. \\
 0.863768 & -1. & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

After scaling:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  F0 10^(-17)/Sqrt[m^2*(w0^2 - w^2)^2 + (k 10^(-13))^2*w^2], {{F0, 
    1.7402685071446624}, {w0, 7.801112679932642}, {k, 
    7.81642643816778}}, w]
nlm["CorrelationMatrix"]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1. & 0.552832 & 0.879581 \\
 0.552832 & 1. & 0.394883 \\
 0.879581 & 0.394883 & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you Jim for you very detailed help and explanation, especially on how to find the starting values.

Comment: +1 To support an argument for "small values," specifically `m` and not the data, note that if `k == 1`, then at machine precision, `m^2*(w0^2 - w^2)^2 + k^2*w^2` will evaluate to `k^2*w^2`, which makes the problem impossible to solve. Even at high working precision, convergence will be difficult. But it suggests a starting value of `{k, m}`, which indeed works, or scaling `k` by `m`. Indeed, there is a similar numerics rounding issue with the correlation matrix, which is fixed by scaling as you show. (Basically, I'm saying what you said from a slightly different point of view.)

Comment: @lio The starting values found by `Solve` and the form of the model imply, to me, that rescaling is needed (per Jim's update).  Even just inspecting the model, one might guess that `k` should be replaced by approximately `k * m` and `F` should be scaled so that `F/m` (or `F/(m Sqrt[2*8^2]`) is approximately the max of the data (the `8` corresponds to the `w` coordinate of the apparent peak in the data).

Answer (score 1):

When the best-fit parameter values are far from 1 (as they will be for your data), you can help Mathematica by providing "initial guesses" for them.  Instead of providing the parameters in the form `{w0, k, F0}`, provide them in the form `{{w0, [guess for w0]}, {k, [guess for k]}, {F0, [guess for F0]}}`, where you replace quantities in square brackets with numbers that you suspect are close to the "real" values.   Mathematica will then be able to refine these guesses to get a best fit.

Comment: This is all in the documentation, BTW;  see the section under "Basic Examples" that starts "Give starting values when parameters are far from the default value 1."

Comment: Show us what you got? The problem is that the original data is very close to zero everywhere.

Comment: @MMM:  I'm reluctant to provide a complete answer because this looks like a homework/lab assignment.  I'll note, however, that the problem isn't so much that all of the data is close to zero;  it's that a particular parameter is several orders of magnitude less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies, I made a comment that you hadn't read the documentation because at first read (and on my phone) I thought you weren't calling the nonlinear model obtained with `NonlinearModelFit` correctly and this doesn't seem to be the case at hand.

I think your problem is one of precision where you are telling mathematica to minimise something that includes a subtraction with a scale factor of $ \sim 10^{-26} $ in your denominator (which has been observed by Jim Baldwin). When you try to increase precision mathematica complains about the precision of the data which is an indication that scaling is an issue. And since the scaling is not really important you can just find the fit omitting the `m` term:

```
data = Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/X7tZeQni"];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, F0/Sqrt[(w0^2 - w^2)^2 + k^2*w^2], {w0, k, F0}, w];

Show[ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"omega", "amplitude"}], 
 Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 40}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

and depending on your confidence of the accuracy of `m` scale the parameters back to their physically meaningful scale.

Comment: What is the "subtraction with a scale factor of $\sim 10^{-26}$"?  I'm not seeing that.